# How to multiple insert without running multiple SQL queries in MatLab?

Tags: sql-server, matlab

I'm using `MatLab R2008b` and `SQL Server 2005`.

I have a large amount of data, in matrix form, that I'd like to insert in SQL Server. But looping through it and running multiple `insert` queries takes a long time. Is there a way to kind of batch or bulk `insert`?

Comment: not really. `insert` is basically "insert one record". inserting multiple records requires multiples `insert` queries, unless you're on a DB that has non-standard extensions, like mysql's multi-value insert: `insert ... values (a,b,c), (d,e,f), ...`

Comment: I suggest you to use SQL Server to import your data by using `OPENROWSET` and `INSERT FROM` ;).